# How to add parameters to a GET request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, websocket

I am trying to access the different information from the following api:https://api.coinnest.co.kr/doc/public.html and stumped in trying to get data for all the different parameters for the /api/pub/ticker request

Here is the code I have written so far, but i cant seem to get any different info for different parameters and end up getting the same information. For example how would i access the data for neo, using it as a parameter

```
var request = require('request')

console.log('requesting market data from coinnest');
request('https://api.coinnest.co.kr/api/pub/ticker/neo',(err,res,body) =>{
    try{
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        var markets = [];
        console.log(body);
    }catch(err){
        console.log('coinnest parsing error');
    }
});
```

If someone could help give me some advice in what i am doing wrong it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which query parameter you wanted to send?

Comment: any one besides the one that is default which is btc. In the code above i am trying to query the neo parameter

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sending any parameters in your GET request, hence you get the response for BTC by default as stated in the API doc.

Send the parameter by appending the URL with ?coin=*coinnamehere*

The following would give you the data for Ethereum.

```
request('https://api.coinnest.co.kr/api/pub/ticker?coin=eth',(err,res,body) =>{
    try{
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        var markets = [];
        console.log(body);
    }catch(err){
        console.log('coinnest parsing error');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks didnt know you could just do that!really apprecaited

Comment: It should be `?coin=${type}` and `neo` is obsolete

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can pass parameters to get request,

```
var request = require('request')

console.log('requesting market data from coinnest');
let options = {
    url: "https://api.coinnest.co.kr/api/pub/ticker",
    method: 'GET',
    qs: {
        coin: 'neo'
    }
}
request(options,(err,res,body) =>{
    try{
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        var markets = [];
        console.log(body);
    }catch(err){
        console.log('coinnest parsing error');
    }
});
```

In above example `options.qs` is the query parameter in which you can pass whatever query parameter you want to pass or else you can simply run

```
request('https://api.coinnest.co.kr/api/pub/ticker?coin=neo',(err,res,body) =>{
    try{
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        var markets = [];
        console.log(body);
    }catch(err){
        console.log('coinnest parsing error');
    }
});
```